# Custom build rule not getting executed for Xcode 6.3

Tags: j2objc

I am trying to get j2Objc working with the XCode build rules setup as explained [in the j2Objc Wiki](https://github.com/google/j2objc/wiki/Xcode-Build-Rules#adding-a-j2objc-build-rule).
The problem that I am facing is that the custom build rule which I add for compiling the java files doesn't seem to get executed at all.
I have tried to add all kinds of simple build rules which will just echo something but nothing shows up in the build log.

[image: Reference image from my project]

The app is a simple single view iOS only application.

Can anyone help me out with figuring out why custom build rules will not work ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure the Process dropdown has "Java source files" Also, make sure you've added your Java source to the Xcode project. See steps 1 and 7 of the wiki documentation that you referenced for more details.

Answer (score 1):

The wiki page says to use a "Java source files", not "Interface Builder Storyboard files" as your screen capture shows. You also need to define an output file, or Xcode ignores the rule (since it doesn't generate anything).

I just verified that adding a Java source file to a 6.3.1 project works with the wiki page's instructions. Be sure that your app is selected in the "Add to targets:" when adding the Java source file.

Project:   [image]

Build log: [image]